# websockets closing unexpectedly

Tags: python, networking, websocket, network-programming

**Update 13. Apr:** dart code works consistently

## Background:

My TV (Samsung 2019 RU7000) offers a secure websocket connection with which json packets can be send to remote control it. For example

```
"method":"ms.remote.control", 
"params":{ "Cmd": "Click", "DataOfCmd":"KEY_MUTE" }
```

can be send to mute the TV.

To enable access, a handshake is done. The client connects to `wss://ip:8002/api/v2/samsung.remote.control?name=value` where the value of `name` is a base64 encoded string. After a successful connection, a popup window appears on the TV which needs to be accepted. If the user accepts the request, the TV sends a JSON response containing a token:

```
"data":{
    "clients":[ ... ],
    "id":"...",
    "token":"28852140"
},
"event":"ms.channel.connect"
```

This token is used for authenticating connections with the same name by attaching `&token=value` to the URL. Sending commands before the user accepts the popup is ignored.

### What works

Command line approaches with `wscat` and `curl` are working. The TV shows a pop-up and sends a response:

```
$ wscat -n -c https://192.168.0.227:8002/api/v2/channels/samsung.remote.control?name=aW9Ccm9rZXI=
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
< {"data":{"clients":[...], "id":"...", "token":"57940060"}, "event":"ms.channel.connect"}
```

#### dart - [dart.io.WebSocket](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-io/WebSocket-class.html)

The following code triggers the popup and gets a response as well.

```
  WebSocket ws = await WebSocket.connect(url,
      compression: CompressionOptions.compressionOff);
  ws.pingInterval = Duration(seconds: 10000);

  ws.listen(print, onError: print, onDone: () {
    print("done");
    print(ws.closeCode);
    print(ws.closeReason);
  });

  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30));
  ws.close();
```

---

## Problem

I want to use python to connect to the websocket, authenticate my session and send remote control commands. This does not work for the following implementations.

#### python - websocket [liris](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client)

The popup does not appear and there is no response from the TV. The socket does not close.

```
from websocket import create_connection
from ssl import CERT_NONE 

sock = create_connection(url, sslopt={"cert_reqs": CERT_NONE})

print(sock.recv())
```

#### python - websockets [aaugustin](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets)

The pop-up does not appear as well and it seems the connection is closed by the TV.

```
from websockets.client import connect, WebSocketClientProtocol
import ssl
import asyncio

async def connect():
    async with connect(url, ssl=ssl.CERT_NONE) as websocket:
        res = await websocket.recv()
        print(res)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connect())
```

The [wireshark log](https://gist.github.com/jnnksdev/e186ca4a73f635d89e543a77e468fe80) shows that it's sending an HTTP GET asking for a websocket upgrade. The TV responds by closing the connection with FIN and RST.

---

### Observations

Connections to publicly available websocket servers do not share the same issues I am experiencing.

Many popular remote controls available for python have the two websocket libraries as the implemented solution. None of these were working for me.

Comparing the packets sent by the python implementations and the command line tools do not show a noticeable difference to me.

wscat sends an 80 byte long packet to the TV every four seconds. I suppose this is ping/pong.

#### How can I investigate further?

Comment: Are you sure the websocket library you are using actually works?

Comment: it's [websocket_client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/)

Comment: For dart are you printing the output? To me it seems like you are only printing the closeCode and reason, should there be an output on WebSocket?

Comment: I'm printing everything I can. The first parameter of [WebSocket.listen](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) is a function with one parameter, that takes in all data arriving, same for `onError.` Instead of using a lambda, I passed the `print` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about trying Tornado's websocket implementation?

```
async def samsung_ws():
    ws_req = HTTPRequest("wss://ip:8002/api/v2/samsung.remote.control?name=value", validate_cert=False)
    ws = await websocket_connect(ws_req)
    ws.write_message("hello")
    while True:
        msg = await ws.read_message()
        if not msg:
            break
        print(msg)
```

Depending on how the webserver is built, you might need to request the webpage before connecting to the websocket because in your `wscat` example I noticed you are using `https://` instead of `wss://`.

Can you post a sample of a dart run (with the `url` used)?

Comment: Thanks, `tornado.websocket` works. I'll try out the other libraries. Maybe it was just the fact, that I had to send a request before building a websocket connection.

Comment: For completions sake: wscat works with both `wss://` and `https://`, while dart only accepts `wss://`

Comment: thank you for the bounty; happy to hear it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Um.... I have some experience on websockets connection using python websockets.
In article, you indicate that your websockets connections will automatically disconnected from the server.

I think is the mechanism call "ping-pong" in the websockets module cause this problem.

The mechanism default status is true, that means you will send a ping sign to the websocket server periodically, if the server doesn't send pong back to you, module will consider that server have been shutdown.So you need to do is just set the "ping-pong"

```
status to False.

    async def connect():
    async with connect(url, ssl=ssl.CERT_NONE,close_timeout = None,ping_interval = None) as websocket:
        res = await websocket.recv()
        print(res)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connect())
```

This is all my personal opinion, you can try this out.

Answer (score -1):

Why not using a higher level Python module like `requests`?
You could try the following:

```
import requests

params = (
    ('name', 'aW9Ccm9rZXI='),
)

response = requests.get('https://192.168.0.227:8002/api/v2/channels/samsung.remote.control', params=params)
```

Comment: As of my understanding websockets is already the higher level module. A websocket connection needs to be 'built' with an exchange of get requests to settle on details, like compression and encryption.

Comment: I already tried this approach, `response.text` is `<html><body>404</body></html>`. But it triggers the pop-up...

Comment: @jnnksdev so, you want to bypass the pop-up authentication? that is the actual question? authentication without triggering the pop-up window --authentication in the background--